# VC++: how-to convert CString to TCHAR*

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

VC++: how-to convert CString value to TCHAR*.One method is GetBuffer(..) function. Is there any other way we can convert CString to TCHAR*.

Comment: Why is GetBuffer not an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CString::GetBuffer()` doesn't make any conversion, it gives direct access to string.

To make a copy of `CString`:

```
TCHAR* buf = _tcsdup(str);
free(buf);
```

or

```
TCHAR* buf = new TCHAR[str.GetLength() + 1];
_tcscpy_s(buf, str.GetLength() + 1, str);
delete[]buf;
```

However the above code is usually not useful. You might want to modify it like so:

```
TCHAR buf[300];
_tcscpy_s(buf, TEXT("text"));
```

Usually you need to this to read data in to buffer, so you want to make the buffer size larger than the current size.

Or you can just use `CString::GetBuffer()`, again you might want to make the buffer size bigger.

```
GetWindowText(hwnd, str.GetBuffer(300), 300);
str.ReleaseBuffer(); //release immediately
TRACE(TEXT("%s\n"), str);
```

In other cases you need only const cast `const TCHAR* cstr = str;`

Lastly, `TCHAR` is not very useful. If your code is compatible with both ANSI and unicode then you might as well make it unicode only. But that's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on why you need a non-const `TCHAR*`. There are two main scenarios:

1. Manual update of the contents of a [CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) object:
   In that case you will have to call [CSimpleStringT::GetBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt26tkzx.aspx) (specifying the minimal length of the final string), update the contents, and call [CSimpleStringT::ReleaseBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32x198c7.aspx). Calling `ReleaseBuffer` is mandatory, as it updates internal state. Failure to call `ReleaseBuffer` can lead to the string exposing unexpected behavior.
2. Failure to expose const-correctness at an interface:
   If this is the case you can either update the interface to take a `const TCHAR*` instead of a `TCHAR*`, and invoke [CSimpleStringT::operator PCXSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk1z2hd9.aspx) by passing the `CString` object.
   If you cannot update the interface, you are best advised to make a copy into a `TCHAR` array and pass a pointer to this copy.
   If you can make sure that the implementation will not ever modify the contents referenced through the `TCHAR*` parameter, you could use a `const_cast` instead. This is not recommended, as it can introduce bugs in the future, by modifying unrelated code.